# laravel pass 2 dimensional array in view

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

i want to pas an array in the view view

controller code is

```
$data['medications'] = array('medicine' => 'meds',
                             'dosage' => 'dosage');

return view('medications.index', $data);
```

i cant retrieve it in view using for each

```
@foreach($medications as $data)
  {{$data->medicine}}//this results in "Trying to get property of non-object"
  {{$data['medicine']}}//this results in "Illegal string offset 'medicine'"
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this.

```
@foreach($medications as $data)
         {{$data}}
    @endforeach
```

Because the here $medication is the array that you make in 
$data['medications'] = array('medicine' => 'meds',
                             'dosage' => 'dosage');

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$data`

```
   @foreach($medications as $data)
         {{$data}}
    @endforeach
```